# Travel Trip Diaries

Tags: data-request, transportation, travel

I am building an agent based traffic micro simulation and am looking for travel trip diaries of an individuals trips on a specific day. Usually, the trip will be done by origin, destination, mode of transport, and unique person.

The ones I am finding online are missing the micro level details of the origin and destination.

Comment: http://www.asdfree.com/2014/03/analyze-national-household-travel.html

Comment: It is going to be difficult to get this information as the micro level data is purposefully aggregated to maintain anonymity for survey participants. You would need to contact the your local department of transportation and work with them directly.

Comment: How many records to you need? For instance 1 or 10, or maybe at least 10.000?

Answer (score 0):

*This is a bit of a stretch,* but consider using the Twitter public feed for travel itineraries that are posted automatically. I noticed on Steve Woz's feed, that he uses Swarm App which posts his travel plans automatically

[image]

([direct link](https://twitter.com/stevewoz/status/938013284791447557))

The raw JSON data for this tweet looks like this:

```
{  
   "created_at":"Tue Dec 05 11:52:49 +0000 2017",
   "id":938013284791447557,
   "id_str":"938013284791447557",
   "text":"Arrival of JL 773 NRT to MEL. (@ Melbourne Airport (MEL) - @melair in Tullamarine, VIC) https:\/\/t.co\/1vKdelQtqZ",
   "truncated":false,
   "entities":{  
      "hashtags":[  

      ],
      "symbols":[  

      ],
      "user_mentions":[  
         {  
            "screen_name":"Melair",
            "name":"Melbourne Airport",
            "id":29406687,
            "id_str":"29406687",
            "indices":[  
               59,
               66
            ]
         }
      ],
      "urls":[  
         {  
            "url":"https:\/\/t.co\/1vKdelQtqZ",
            "expanded_url":"https:\/\/www.swarmapp.com\/c\/4tuxJ7eGzTS",
            "display_url":"swarmapp.com\/c\/4tuxJ7eGzTS",
            "indices":[  
               88,
               111
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/foursquare.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFoursquare\u003c\/a\u003e",
   "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id":null,
   "in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,
   "in_reply_to_screen_name":null,
   "user":{  
      "id":22938914,
      "id_str":"22938914",
      "name":"Steve Wozniak",
      "screen_name":"stevewoz",
      "location":"Los Gatos, California",
      "description":"Engineers first! Human rights. Gadgets. Jokes and pranks. Segways. Music and concerts. Gameboy Tetris.",
      "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/gC1NnB1hgl",
      "entities":{  
         "url":{  
            "urls":[  
               {  
                  "url":"http:\/\/t.co\/gC1NnB1hgl",
                  "expanded_url":"http:\/\/woz.org",
                  "display_url":"woz.org",
                  "indices":[  
                     0,
                     22
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         "description":{  
            "urls":[  

            ]
         }
      },
      "protected":false,
      "followers_count":599511,
      "friends_count":89,
      "listed_count":9677,
      "created_at":"Thu Mar 05 16:24:20 +0000 2009",
      "favourites_count":21,
      "utc_offset":-28800,
      "time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
      "geo_enabled":true,
      "verified":true,
      "statuses_count":6504,
      "lang":"en",
      "contributors_enabled":false,
      "is_translator":false,
      "is_translation_enabled":false,
      "profile_background_color":"9AE4E8",
      "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme16\/bg.gif",
      "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme16\/bg.gif",
      "profile_background_tile":false,
      "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1365311061\/Janet_and_Woz_normal.jpg",
      "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1365311061\/Janet_and_Woz_normal.jpg",
      "profile_link_color":"0084B4",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color":"BDDCAD",
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDFFCC",
      "profile_text_color":"333333",
      "profile_use_background_image":true,
      "has_extended_profile":false,
      "default_profile":false,
      "default_profile_image":false,
      "following":false,
      "follow_request_sent":false,
      "notifications":false,
      "translator_type":"none"
   },
   "geo":{  
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[  
         -37.67034562,
         144.84909363
      ]
   },
   "coordinates":{  
      "type":"Point",
      "coordinates":[  
         144.84909363,
         -37.67034562
      ]
   },
   "place":{  
      "id":"01864a8a64df9dc4",
      "url":"https:\/\/api.twitter.com\/1.1\/geo\/id\/01864a8a64df9dc4.json",
      "place_type":"city",
      "name":"Melbourne",
      "full_name":"Melbourne, Victoria",
      "country_code":"AU",
      "country":"Australia",
      "contained_within":[  

      ],
      "bounding_box":{  
         "type":"Polygon",
         "coordinates":[  
            [  
               [  
                  144.593741856,
                  -38.433859306
               ],
               [  
                  145.512528832,
                  -38.433859306
               ],
               [  
                  145.512528832,
                  -37.5112737225
               ],
               [  
                  144.593741856,
                  -37.5112737225
               ]
            ]
         ]
      },
      "attributes":{  

      }
   },
   "contributors":null,
   "is_quote_status":false,
   "retweet_count":2,
   "favorite_count":19,
   "favorited":false,
   "retweeted":false,
   "possibly_sensitive":false,
   "possibly_sensitive_appealable":false,
   "lang":"en"
}
```

And you can see that the source is labeled as `href=\"http:\/\/foursquare.com\`

With the [Twitter Search API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html) you can search for keywords up to one week old, perhaps by JSON field `source` as well. You can download and then scan for relevant itineraries: `JL 773 NRT to MEL` = `Japan Airlnes Flight 773 from Narita to Melbourne`